# Does this NSLOOKUP timeout with ZoneEdit mean their DNS servers are down?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

My DNS zone record appears to be degrading. NSLOOKUP on www.whatpub.org gives a timeout. Am I right in saying this means the two ZoneEdit nameservers I use (ns2.zoneedit.com & ns17.zoneedit.com) are not responding to requests?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question, yes NS2 and NS17 are both currently down although the status page says everything is okay. Found a few twitter posts. So it's a case of sit tight...

Answer (score 0):

ZoneEdit.com is up and down.  See http://zoneedit.com/status.html